# Transaction details not showing in magento1.9 in order details

Tags: magento, paypal, transactions, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 when user create an order and pay with paypal adaptive payment the transaction details are not showing in order but previously it was working.

Comment: have you checked the logs? any further information? some more details are needed to help you

Comment: Check your PayPal IPN to see if there is any retrying